# Resize Header On Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, navigation

I'm trying to change the header size (which I named `#headwrapper`) and its background color when scrolling down. As you can see I need it to trigger the class `.small` when scrolling is > 145.

It is working only when I minimize the screen's width to `600px` or less. 
I have this problem since I had to change the very last line from `height: '130px'` to `height: 'auto'; max-height: '1000px'`. This in order to fully see the drop down menu triggered when the screens width is `600px`. It was cutting in half with height `130px`.

This is the script:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
    if (sc > 145) {
        $("#pageheader, #headwrapper, #main-nav, .logos, #social, #main-  logo").addClass("small");
    } 
    else {
        $("#pageheader, #headwrapper, #main-nav, .logos, #social, #main-  logo").removeClass("small")
    }
});

$(function(){
    $('#headwrapper').data('size', 'big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
        if ($('#headwrapper').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#headwrapper').data('size', 'small');
            $('#headwrapper').stop().animate({
                height:'75px'
            }, 400);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#headwrapper').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#headwrapper').data('size', 'big');
            $('#headwrapper').stop().animate({
                height: 'auto'; 
                max-height: '1000px'
            }, 400);
        }  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the animate object syntax. Replace the `;` with `,` and quote them:

```
$('#headwrapper').stop().animate({
  "height": 'auto',       // Change ; to , as this is an object.
  "max-height": '1000px'
}, 400);
```

And move everything inside the `document`'s `ready` function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#headwrapper').data('size','big');
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (sc > 145) {
      $("#pageheader,#headwrapper,#main-nav,.logos,#social,#main-  logo").addClass("small");
    } 
    else {
      $("#pageheader,#headwrapper,#main-nav,.logos,#social,#main-  logo").removeClass("small");
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
      if($('#headwrapper').data('size') == 'big') {
        $('#headwrapper').data('size','small');
        $('#headwrapper').stop().animate({
          height:'75px'
        },400);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if($('#headwrapper').data('size') == 'small') {
        $('#headwrapper').data('size','big');
        $('#headwrapper').stop().animate({
          "height": 'auto',
          "max-height": '1000px'
        },400);
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Prave Kumar. I did as you suggested but it does not trigger the class .small either... It only gets triggered if width is 600px or less.

Comment: @Alessandro Do you get any errors in teh console? Can you create a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: Kumar - no error in the console. This is JSFiddle. Hope it can be clearer. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=EFEgolttls

Comment: Call me `Praveen`. The fiddle URL is bogus. I clearly asked you to create a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: Ok Praveen - how about I link you the website so you can see it fully? Thanks for your help. www.alessandro-dandrea.com

Comment: @Alessandro Good, that would do.

Comment: Hi Praveen - any luck with it?

Comment: @Alessandro Tough buddy... Lot of errors in your page.

Comment: Thanks Praveen - I am in learning path with JS and Jquery.. Hope you can sort it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96676/discussion-between-alessandro-and-praveen-kumar).